# Basic Express Server

Tags: node.js, express, get

```
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join('/index.html'));
});

app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
    res.send('contact');
});

app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join('/index.html'));
});
```

First get works fine and gets the page. Second get works and displays a string at a different url...but when I combine the two (page that previously displayed and address that previously displayed something) it says Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/index.html' . Any clues why this isn't working?

Part 2: do I need to use path and public directory, or is there a simpler way to send files directly from the project folder like a simple node server does?

Comment: FYI, `path.join('/index.html')` makes no sense.  The purpose of `path.join()` is to combine multiple paths together, not to use it on a single path.  Perhaps you meant to use `path.join(__dirname, 'index.html')` to serve the file from your project directory? or `path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html')` to serve if from a sub-directory of your project named `public`.

Comment: What exact code gives you ENOENT?

Comment: The entire code I'm using is 
```
let express = require('express');
const app = express();
var path = require('path');


app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join('/index.html'));
});


app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join('/index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000, ()=> console.log('listening!'));

```
the specific part triggering the error is that third get request

```
app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join('/index.html'));
});

Comment: Which route gives you ENOENT?  And, did you read and understand my first comment?

Comment: I think I understand your comment. I copied the first part of this code and since the first get worked I thought it was correct...I guess I assumed that path was creating the functionality of accessing things in the public folder without specifying that, but what you say makes sense. The error actually come up when I delete the second get (forgot to mention this) so that it doesn't just return "contact" and then go to http://localhost:3000/contact

Comment: Well, you say the first route works and the 3rd route doesn't yet (after you remove the 2nd route), but that doesn't make sense since the two route handlers contain the exact same code.  So, something else is different from what you're showing here.  Chance are the solution is you just need to build the right path to your file, but you don't tell us where it is so we don't know how to help you do that.

Comment: I think that fundamentally figuring out the paths and routes for files are what I don't understand enough. I'm not even sure what a route is, so I guess I need to research that. I did eventually figure out that probably what was happening here is that neither of my gets was working, but the first one appeared to be because something (express? express.static?) was automatically serving all the HTML files that were in the public folder. So, that makes a little more sense.

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense.  A route in this context is something like `app.get(somePath, someHandler)`.  There is an incoming request path that you wrote specific code for to send a certain response for.  Middleware like `app.use(express.static(...))` might send files for lots of incoming requests.

Comment: So, it sounds like you can either let `express.static()` handle these for you or you need to fix the construction of the proper path like I suggested in my first comment.